# How can I make an auto update feature in my app

Tags: android

I have an app that plays some videos. Links go down all the time. What I want to do is be able update it with out customers having to download a new version of my app every time. At the moment my update feature just consists of a button. Which when pressed takes you to media fire to download a new version. It's time consuming and constantly fills your hdd with new versions. Any help would be brilliant guys thanks.

Comment: "i have an app that plays some videos. Links go down all the time. What I want to do is be able update it with out customers having to download a new version of my app every time. "  update what?

Comment: Why dont you serve the links from a server database? and then when you change them, use push notifications to update the devices?  or just make the app download the links from the server once a day (if there was a change of course)

Comment: I have push notifactions but only know how to send text is there away to use push notifactions to actually update

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a REST service, you can make with any language. Then your app will be always up-to-date without any update.

Comment: Something like this you mean?http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes

Comment: You will have a server which return json and then do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/3546760

Comment: No. The only thing that it does its to have an online database instead of local.

Answer (score -2):

Auto-update is already supported by Google Play and it is done on background. I see no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to publish the app on the play store?

Comment: I think he means to update the content without updating the app. In that case he needs to use a REST API and that's it.

Comment: *I think he means to update the content without updating the app* and that's why your answer tells something different?

Comment: It's not published on playstore. I want to be able to do it all my self. I can write a data base but the php bit baffles me at mo. But wat is a rest api